# Gurobi solver gets stuck in "Root Simplex" after finding optimal solution using Pyomo

Tags: optimization, pyomo, gurobi

I am not sure if this question is adequate for StackOverflow as it may as well be a Gurobi problem. I have a large Mixed-Integer Linear Programming Model and it solves fine with Gurobi for certain inputs. However, sometimes Gurobi finds an optimal solution but then never finishes the optimization and it seems to get stuck in the last step before showing the result. It just stops logging or doing anything at this step:

```
Root simplex log...

Iteration    Objective       Primal Inf.    Dual Inf.      Time
  428736   -4.0861847e+06   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00    928s
  428736   -4.0861847e+06   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00    931s
```

According the gurobi documentation zeros at Primal Inf. and Dual Inf. indicate that the optimization finished successfully and it should proceed with the results, which it doesn't do for me.
Has anybody experienced something like this before? And if yes how did you solve it?

Thanks heaps for the help!

Axel

Attached the complete gurobi log first without and then with numeric issues (ignore the different optimal objectives, there was different input involved):

```
Reading time = 51.00 seconds
x6132333: 4380233 rows, 5606696 columns, 19863046 nonzeros
Changed value of parameter NodefileStart to 0.5
   Prev: inf  Min: 0.0  Max: inf  Default: inf
Gurobi Optimizer version 9.1.1 build v9.1.1rc0 (win64)
Thread count: 4 physical cores, 8 logical processors, using up to 8 threads
Optimize a model with 4380233 rows, 5606696 columns and 19863046 nonzeros
Model fingerprint: 0x17dfc5bb
Variable types: 5431496 continuous, 175200 integer (175200 binary)
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [1e-03, 1e+05]
  Objective range  [4e-01, 1e+00]
  Bounds range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  RHS range        [6e-01, 1e+05]
Presolve removed 2497233 rows and 2760350 columns (presolve time = 7s) ...
Presolve removed 2956433 rows and 3219550 columns (presolve time = 10s) ...
Presolve removed 2956433 rows and 3219550 columns (presolve time = 15s) ...
Presolve removed 2956433 rows and 3219550 columns (presolve time = 22s) ...
Presolve removed 2956433 rows and 3219550 columns (presolve time = 29s) ...
Presolve removed 2956433 rows and 3219550 columns
Presolve time: 28.91s
Presolved: 1423800 rows, 2387146 columns, 7371279 nonzeros
Variable types: 2387146 continuous, 0 integer (0 binary)

Deterministic concurrent LP optimizer: primal simplex, dual simplex, and barrier
Showing barrier log only...

Root barrier log...

Ordering time: 0.49s

Barrier statistics:
 Dense cols : 6
 AA' NZ     : 5.240e+06
 Factor NZ  : 2.070e+07 (roughly 1.7 GBytes of memory)
 Factor Ops : 3.802e+08 (less than 1 second per iteration)
 Threads    : 2

                  Objective                Residual
Iter       Primal          Dual         Primal    Dual     Compl     Time
   0  -7.96402087e+09  6.37761100e+09  1.38e+08 2.46e+00  2.76e+06    54s
   1  -5.94227013e+09  6.25214767e+09  9.98e+07 6.98e+01  1.88e+06    56s
   2  -4.33580986e+09  6.30244644e+09  7.05e+07 1.69e+01  1.24e+06    58s
   3  -3.89766275e+09  1.13309314e+10  6.44e+07 8.59e+00  1.22e+06    60s
   4  -2.13922340e+09  1.15274975e+10  3.06e+07 4.72e+00  5.81e+05    64s
   5  -1.34252657e+09  1.21554436e+10  1.25e+07 7.46e-01  2.35e+05    66s
   6  -8.70308400e+08  1.19616415e+10  6.19e+06 5.41e-02  1.15e+05    68s
   7  -8.23052754e+08  1.15804774e+10  5.63e+06 2.87e-02  1.03e+05    70s
   8  -7.18259717e+08  1.11971437e+10  3.93e+06 1.48e-02  7.20e+04    72s
   9  -6.14880956e+08  1.05514145e+10  2.27e+06 6.68e-03  4.18e+04    74s
  10  -2.87973249e+08  8.21789507e+09  1.74e+05 4.88e-07  4.52e+03    75s
  11  -1.14443932e+08  2.98342594e+09  3.51e+04 3.29e-07  1.02e+03    77s
  12  -9.83082800e+07  1.81791990e+09  2.26e+04 1.99e-07  5.85e+02    79s
  13  -7.98538149e+07  1.12632964e+09  1.62e+04 1.10e-07  3.55e+02    81s
  14  -7.40060248e+07  9.38255705e+08  1.38e+04 9.07e-08  2.90e+02    83s
  15  -5.70358448e+07  7.58113891e+08  7.52e+03 6.94e-08  2.05e+02    85s
  16  -5.38442966e+07  7.48524984e+08  6.82e+03 6.86e-08  1.99e+02    88s
  17  -3.96209289e+07  6.31776871e+08  3.41e+03 5.70e-08  1.56e+02    91s
  18  -3.35024686e+07  5.90860057e+08  3.50e+00 5.28e-08  1.41e+02    94s
  19  -2.45797994e+07  2.03056861e+08  2.30e+00 1.53e-08  5.07e+01    99s
  20  -1.53792929e+07  3.92734746e+07  1.17e+00 1.63e-09  1.17e+01   102s
  21  -1.04398368e+07  1.27747764e+07  6.27e-01 9.34e-10  4.83e+00   105s
  22  -6.93026339e+06  5.73390984e+06  2.98e-01 4.81e-10  2.58e+00   107s
  23  -6.54744053e+06  2.77192760e+06  2.66e-01 3.03e-10  1.89e+00   109s
  24  -5.17200122e+06  7.65982514e+05  1.55e-01 2.23e-10  1.20e+00   111s
  25  -4.92172096e+06 -6.97616280e+05  1.35e-01 1.36e-10  8.50e-01   113s
  26  -4.36714053e+06 -1.40675070e+06  9.05e-02 1.05e-10  5.95e-01   115s
  27  -4.04669015e+06 -2.25777348e+06  6.47e-02 4.82e-11  3.59e-01   117s
  28  -3.75439120e+06 -2.60591950e+06  4.20e-02 4.17e-11  2.30e-01   120s
  29  -3.60373763e+06 -2.85673836e+06  3.06e-02 2.33e-11  1.50e-01   123s
  30  -3.50975398e+06 -2.96490882e+06  2.27e-02 1.64e-11  1.09e-01   126s
  31  -3.44481481e+06 -3.05661234e+06  1.71e-02 6.23e-12  7.77e-02   129s
  32  -3.41209626e+06 -3.09530195e+06  1.41e-02 1.29e-10  6.34e-02   131s
  33  -3.38231320e+06 -3.11178512e+06  1.16e-02 8.10e-12  5.41e-02   133s
  34  -3.35525731e+06 -3.14352761e+06  9.42e-03 2.04e-10  4.24e-02   136s
  35  -3.32615252e+06 -3.17584264e+06  6.86e-03 1.63e-10  3.01e-02   139s
  36  -3.30893392e+06 -3.19769591e+06  5.30e-03 3.01e-10  2.22e-02   143s
  37  -3.29483648e+06 -3.20821569e+06  4.00e-03 2.19e-10  1.73e-02   147s
  38  -3.28214956e+06 -3.22153938e+06  2.81e-03 3.72e-10  1.21e-02   150s
  39  -3.28058920e+06 -3.22508398e+06  2.66e-03 3.33e-10  1.11e-02   154s
  40  -3.27134935e+06 -3.23139910e+06  1.73e-03 2.55e-12  7.99e-03   157s
  41  -3.26658024e+06 -3.23571862e+06  1.26e-03 3.13e-10  6.17e-03   161s
  42  -3.26504758e+06 -3.23932726e+06  1.12e-03 6.84e-10  5.14e-03   165s
  43  -3.26075768e+06 -3.24219157e+06  7.12e-04 1.18e-09  3.71e-03   169s
  44  -3.25857520e+06 -3.24577296e+06  4.92e-04 1.53e-09  2.56e-03   172s
  45  -3.25777564e+06 -3.24768022e+06  4.17e-04 1.47e-09  2.02e-03   177s
  46  -3.25718894e+06 -3.24908419e+06  3.68e-04 1.29e-09  1.62e-03   181s
  47  -3.25665643e+06 -3.24928768e+06  3.21e-04 1.27e-09  1.47e-03   184s
  48  -3.25601298e+06 -3.24958294e+06  2.63e-04 1.19e-09  1.28e-03   187s
  49  -3.25575430e+06 -3.24994390e+06  2.37e-04 1.11e-09  1.16e-03   191s
  50  -3.25525851e+06 -3.25010504e+06  1.92e-04 1.05e-09  1.03e-03   195s
  51  -3.25485639e+06 -3.25040895e+06  1.54e-04 9.83e-10  8.88e-04   199s
  52  -3.25468597e+06 -3.25083749e+06  1.31e-04 8.82e-10  7.69e-04   202s
  53  -3.25432713e+06 -3.25102159e+06  1.01e-04 8.39e-10  6.60e-04   206s
  54  -3.25423403e+06 -3.25120759e+06  9.04e-05 7.72e-10  6.05e-04   210s
  55  -3.25398425e+06 -3.25161450e+06  6.58e-05 6.40e-10  4.73e-04   213s
  56  -3.25376404e+06 -3.25225013e+06  4.31e-05 4.25e-10  3.02e-04   217s
  57  -3.25341893e+06 -3.25260504e+06  7.14e-06 3.97e-10  1.63e-04   221s
  58  -3.25337487e+06 -3.25272062e+06  3.53e-06 5.71e-10  1.31e-04   224s
  59  -3.25335706e+06 -3.25298271e+06  1.56e-06 4.14e-10  7.48e-05   227s
  60  -3.25334256e+06 -3.25319898e+06  8.69e-07 3.76e-10  2.87e-05   229s
  61  -3.25333311e+06 -3.25331716e+06  1.46e-07 5.04e-12  3.19e-06   231s
  62  -3.25333128e+06 -3.25332901e+06  1.32e-08 2.59e-09  4.53e-07   233s
  63  -3.25333104e+06 -3.25333096e+06  3.72e-09 5.05e-10  1.61e-08   235s
  64  -3.25333104e+06 -3.25333097e+06  2.12e-06 4.89e-10  1.47e-08   237s
  65  -3.25333104e+06 -3.25333097e+06  2.12e-06 4.90e-10  1.47e-08   240s
  66  -3.25333104e+06 -3.25333097e+06  2.12e-06 4.91e-10  1.47e-08   242s

Barrier solved model in 66 iterations and 242.12 seconds
Optimal objective -3.25333104e+06


Root crossover log...

  156796 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               247s
    7788 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               250s
    6612 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               255s
    3346 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               261s
       0 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               263s

  808250 PPushes remaining with PInf 3.8126575e-05               264s
  278348 PPushes remaining with PInf 6.2504638e-04               266s
   10299 PPushes remaining with PInf 0.0000000e+00               270s
       0 PPushes remaining with PInf 0.0000000e+00               274s

  Push phase complete: Pinf 0.0000000e+00, Dinf 1.0527954e-01    274s


Root simplex log...

Iteration    Objective       Primal Inf.    Dual Inf.      Time
  965029   -3.2533310e+06   0.000000e+00   1.052795e-01    274s
  965072   -3.2533310e+06   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00    275s
  965072   -3.2533310e+06   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00    279s
```

```
Warning: lp file contains 719280 small (<= 1e-13) coefficient(s), ignored
Read LP format model from file C:\Users\abruck\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdsd4lney.pyomo.lp
Reading time = 91.43 seconds
x6132333: 4380213 rows, 5606696 columns, 19604266 nonzeros
Changed value of parameter NodefileStart to 0.5
   Prev: inf  Min: 0.0  Max: inf  Default: inf
Gurobi Optimizer version 9.1.1 build v9.1.1rc0 (win64)
Thread count: 4 physical cores, 8 logical processors, using up to 8 threads
Optimize a model with 4380213 rows, 5606696 columns and 19604266 nonzeros
Model fingerprint: 0x109e0bc2
Variable types: 5431496 continuous, 175200 integer (175200 binary)
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [2e-06, 1e+10]
  Objective range  [4e-01, 1e+00]
  Bounds range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  RHS range        [1e+00, 1e+10]
Warning: Model contains large matrix coefficient range
Warning: Model contains large rhs
         Consider reformulating model or setting NumericFocus parameter
         to avoid numerical issues.
Presolve removed 2204513 rows and 1657004 columns (presolve time = 5s) ...
Presolve removed 2670233 rows and 3523854 columns (presolve time = 11s) ...
Presolve removed 2802853 rows and 3656474 columns (presolve time = 15s) ...
Presolve removed 2802853 rows and 3656474 columns (presolve time = 20s) ...
Presolve removed 2802853 rows and 3656474 columns (presolve time = 25s) ...
Presolve removed 2802853 rows and 3656474 columns (presolve time = 30s) ...
Presolve removed 2802856 rows and 3656475 columns (presolve time = 36s) ...
Presolve removed 2802856 rows and 3656475 columns (presolve time = 42s) ...
Presolve removed 2802856 rows and 3656475 columns
Presolve time: 42.40s
Presolved: 1577357 rows, 1950221 columns, 6083666 nonzeros
Variable types: 1950221 continuous, 0 integer (0 binary)

Deterministic concurrent LP optimizer: primal simplex, dual simplex, and barrier
Showing barrier log only...

Root barrier log...

Ordering time: 0.67s

Barrier statistics:
 Dense cols : 6
 AA' NZ     : 4.522e+06
 Factor NZ  : 1.898e+07 (roughly 1.6 GBytes of memory)
 Factor Ops : 2.602e+08 (less than 1 second per iteration)
 Threads    : 2

                  Objective                Residual
Iter       Primal          Dual         Primal    Dual     Compl     Time
   0   4.66756102e+08  8.28662239e+09  3.16e+03 1.95e+00  2.63e+05    70s
   1   3.81301676e+08  8.39150150e+09  2.66e+03 2.47e+02  2.09e+05    73s
   2   3.52804651e+08  8.96812797e+09  2.48e+03 1.54e+02  1.87e+05    76s
   3   1.99652991e+08  9.84544646e+09  1.47e+03 3.54e+01  1.03e+05    81s
   4   1.75245055e+08  1.32198725e+10  1.33e+03 1.59e+01  9.12e+04    84s
   5   7.87857037e+06  1.26340222e+10  3.58e+02 7.66e+00  2.73e+04    87s
   6  -3.68083454e+07  9.13818030e+09  7.30e+01 1.46e+00  6.61e+03    89s
   7  -4.64884080e+07  2.53949243e+09  5.15e+00 6.09e-02  7.62e+02    93s
   8  -2.86534817e+07  3.62143236e+08  3.22e-01 6.23e-03  8.86e+01    95s
   9  -1.31745817e+07  4.94519865e+07  5.27e-02 1.49e-04  1.35e+01    99s
  10  -9.56889244e+06  1.01427080e+07  2.36e-02 2.51e-09  4.19e+00   103s
  11  -7.85831330e+06  6.23301053e+06  1.39e-02 2.62e-09  2.98e+00   107s
  12  -6.87760215e+06  3.78096385e+06  9.82e-03 1.43e-09  2.25e+00   110s
  13  -6.26928421e+06  2.21283636e+06  7.55e-03 1.19e-09  1.79e+00   112s
  14  -6.20370885e+06  1.71278836e+06  7.32e-03 1.02e-09  1.67e+00   115s
  15  -5.84606404e+06  8.02903305e+05  6.02e-03 7.06e-10  1.40e+00   118s
  16  -5.57816290e+06  3.70215276e+05  5.07e-03 9.35e-10  1.25e+00   121s
  17  -5.40206466e+06 -7.35046558e+05  4.43e-03 6.17e-10  9.82e-01   126s
  18  -5.16923570e+06 -2.02868063e+06  3.59e-03 5.30e-10  6.60e-01   131s
  19  -4.96598625e+06 -2.43521715e+06  2.87e-03 2.46e-10  5.32e-01   137s
  20  -4.84865323e+06 -3.17242039e+06  2.44e-03 1.41e-10  3.52e-01   142s
  21  -4.46875398e+06 -3.63253764e+06  9.29e-04 1.07e-10  1.75e-01   147s
  22  -4.33246190e+06 -3.84588891e+06  4.82e-04 2.72e-11  1.02e-01   153s
  23  -4.25735255e+06 -3.93282549e+06  2.51e-04 2.81e-11  6.80e-02   157s
  24  -4.24372118e+06 -3.94786201e+06  2.14e-04 4.25e-11  6.20e-02   161s
  25  -4.23188503e+06 -3.96004133e+06  1.78e-04 3.26e-11  5.70e-02   163s
  26  -4.22403271e+06 -3.97234871e+06  1.56e-04 5.52e-12  5.27e-02   166s
  27  -4.20536512e+06 -3.98751836e+06  1.26e-04 4.23e-11  4.57e-02   169s
  28  -4.18118987e+06 -3.99888501e+06  9.91e-05 4.49e-12  3.82e-02   172s
  29  -4.16846050e+06 -4.01417853e+06  8.55e-05 1.13e-11  3.23e-02   177s
  30  -4.15973236e+06 -4.02560500e+06  7.61e-05 1.67e-11  2.81e-02   181s
  31  -4.15167573e+06 -4.04031662e+06  6.77e-05 8.73e-11  2.33e-02   185s
  32  -4.13871183e+06 -4.04798211e+06  5.41e-05 7.44e-12  1.90e-02   190s
  33  -4.13152745e+06 -4.05726696e+06  4.63e-05 2.01e-11  1.56e-02   195s
  34  -4.12815625e+06 -4.05877485e+06  4.26e-05 2.67e-11  1.45e-02   199s
  35  -4.12306010e+06 -4.06262189e+06  3.77e-05 3.00e-11  1.27e-02   203s
  36  -4.11945299e+06 -4.06367543e+06  3.34e-05 5.10e-11  1.17e-02   207s
  37  -4.11615374e+06 -4.06905375e+06  3.01e-05 4.84e-11  9.87e-03   211s
  38  -4.11151574e+06 -4.07136059e+06  2.54e-05 3.37e-11  8.41e-03   215s
  39  -4.10834862e+06 -4.07469107e+06  2.20e-05 7.42e-11  7.05e-03   219s
  40  -4.10704743e+06 -4.07526754e+06  2.07e-05 9.26e-11  6.66e-03   223s
  41  -4.10491259e+06 -4.07667526e+06  1.86e-05 1.92e-10  5.91e-03   227s
  42  -4.10303187e+06 -4.07695657e+06  1.67e-05 1.98e-10  5.46e-03   231s
  43  -4.10114861e+06 -4.07781343e+06  1.48e-05 2.41e-10  4.89e-03   235s
  44  -4.09910444e+06 -4.07841132e+06  1.26e-05 3.39e-10  4.33e-03   239s
  45  -4.09811867e+06 -4.07912065e+06  1.16e-05 4.34e-10  3.98e-03   244s
  46  -4.09650464e+06 -4.07971227e+06  1.00e-05 4.74e-10  3.52e-03   248s
  47  -4.09633635e+06 -4.07992365e+06  9.86e-06 4.78e-10  3.44e-03   252s
  48  -4.09573883e+06 -4.08058667e+06  9.26e-06 5.16e-10  3.17e-03   256s
  49  -4.09432796e+06 -4.08121481e+06  7.88e-06 5.64e-10  2.75e-03   261s
  50  -4.09418756e+06 -4.08168963e+06  7.74e-06 5.51e-10  2.62e-03   265s
  51  -4.09237431e+06 -4.08200101e+06  5.94e-06 5.62e-10  2.17e-03   269s
  52  -4.09183171e+06 -4.08277521e+06  5.41e-06 5.24e-10  1.90e-03   273s
  53  -4.09131749e+06 -4.08302624e+06  4.91e-06 4.96e-10  1.74e-03   277s
  54  -4.09073574e+06 -4.08315392e+06  4.34e-06 4.71e-10  1.59e-03   282s
  55  -4.08880700e+06 -4.08374246e+06  2.44e-06 4.24e-10  1.06e-03   287s
  56  -4.08824447e+06 -4.08468567e+06  1.89e-06 2.78e-10  7.45e-04   291s
  57  -4.08802720e+06 -4.08504652e+06  1.69e-06 2.11e-10  6.24e-04   295s
  58  -4.08791052e+06 -4.08507727e+06  1.59e-06 2.04e-10  5.93e-04   299s
  59  -4.08707643e+06 -4.08564690e+06  7.99e-07 1.14e-10  2.99e-04   303s
  60  -4.08695229e+06 -4.08576428e+06  6.87e-07 2.39e-10  2.49e-04   308s
  61  -4.08666952e+06 -4.08598019e+06  4.33e-07 2.67e-10  1.44e-04   312s
  62  -4.08660758e+06 -4.08603171e+06  3.79e-07 1.41e-10  1.21e-04   317s
  63  -4.08640686e+06 -4.08604650e+06  1.95e-07 3.07e-11  7.55e-05   320s
  64  -4.08631975e+06 -4.08616253e+06  1.15e-07 2.47e-10  3.29e-05   324s
  65  -4.08620218e+06 -4.08618310e+06  1.40e-08 1.20e-10  4.00e-06   327s
  66  -4.08618536e+06 -4.08618455e+06  5.44e-10 5.38e-10  1.70e-07   330s
  67  -4.08618468e+06 -4.08618468e+06  1.15e-09 1.64e-09  3.56e-10   332s

Barrier solved model in 67 iterations and 332.29 seconds
Optimal objective -4.08618468e+06


Root crossover log...

  652064 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               334s
  319521 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               335s
  276718 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               341s
  276290 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               346s
  275947 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               351s
  275591 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               356s
  275169 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               361s
  274733 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               365s
  274342 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               370s
  133852 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               376s
  121958 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               381s
  116210 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               386s
  112265 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               391s
  108850 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               396s
  105995 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               401s
  103345 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               406s
  101066 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               411s
   98675 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               416s
   96533 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               421s
   94384 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               425s
   92505 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               430s
   89622 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               437s
   87695 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               442s
   85973 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               447s
   84268 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               451s
   82731 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               456s
   81080 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               461s
   79585 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               466s
   77977 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               471s
   76470 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               476s
   74969 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               480s
   73510 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               485s
   72124 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               490s
   70805 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               495s
   68847 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               502s
   67520 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               507s
   66378 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               511s
   65128 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               516s
   64034 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               521s
   62872 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               526s
   61734 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               531s
   60671 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               536s
   59565 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               541s
   58537 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               546s
   57508 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               551s
   56390 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               556s
   55413 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               561s
   54338 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               567s
   53358 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               572s
   52441 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               577s
   51534 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               581s
   50702 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               587s
   49880 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               592s
   49139 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               597s
   48759 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               600s
   48112 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               605s
   47451 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               610s
   46835 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               616s
   46255 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               622s
   45712 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               627s
   45447 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               630s
   44910 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               636s
   44438 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               641s
   43945 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               646s
   43463 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               652s
   42999 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               658s
   42790 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               660s
   42314 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               666s
   41849 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               671s
   41393 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               676s
   40932 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               680s
   40429 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               685s
   39938 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               690s
   39436 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               695s
   38930 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               700s
   38145 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               707s
   37624 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               712s
   37093 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               716s
   36531 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               721s
   36009 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               726s
   35475 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               730s
   34669 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               737s
   34101 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               742s
   33557 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               746s
   32995 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               751s
   32458 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               755s
   31643 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               762s
   31107 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               767s
   30544 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               772s
   29962 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               776s
   29388 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               781s
   28806 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               786s
   28184 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               791s
   27623 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               796s
   26990 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               801s
   26406 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               806s
   25815 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               811s
   25180 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               816s
   24575 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               821s
   23968 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               826s
   23394 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               831s
   22855 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               835s
   22345 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               840s
   21865 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               845s
   21401 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               850s
   20723 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               857s
   20217 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               862s
   19557 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               867s
   19153 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               871s
   18843 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               876s
   18277 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               882s
   17632 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               885s
   15995 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               892s
   14763 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               896s
   12898 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               901s
   11723 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               906s
   11337 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               911s
   10942 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               916s
   10555 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               921s
       0 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00               925s

  198443 PPushes remaining with PInf 2.4354221e-05               925s
       0 PPushes remaining with PInf 0.0000000e+00               927s

  Push phase complete: Pinf 0.0000000e+00, Dinf 1.8299394e-11    927s


Root simplex log...

Iteration    Objective       Primal Inf.    Dual Inf.      Time
  428736   -4.0861847e+06   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00    928s
  428736   -4.0861847e+06   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00    931s
```

Comment: The logs show your model has numerical issues. Can you address that first and try again?

Comment: Thanks Greg, yes I saw this too and closed the matrix range to an acceptable number.  I am still running into the same problem...

Comment: Thanks, kindly post the logs with the numerically cleaner version.

Comment: I did, I reduced the unnecessary Big M values and made some tiny solar irradiance to zero.
Ignore the different objective value. I used different input data

Comment: One thing that I find weird is that it the Root Simplex log gives me twice the same line with : 965072   -3.2533310e+06   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00 ; it should actually be done with the optimisation by then

Comment: Actually, after Presolve this is no longer a MIP. What is happening here?

Comment: I tested the model with the same input files on two computers one with 16 GB RAM and one with 8 GB RAM. Both get stuck at the same step and both find the exact same objective value. The only difference is the time and iterations...
For some other input files the model even ends correctly.

Comment: @Richard good question. I guess it is normal as gurobi tries to simplify the model for an easier solving process wouldn't it? I once had two quadratic constraint by accident in a model and they were also gone after the presolve

Comment: Having quadratic constraints gone is normal (Gurobi automatically linearizes sometimes), however having all of your 175200 binaries removed means that none of them are actually degrees of freedom, i.e. all of them can be fixed without solving the optimization. In my opinion, this means your modeling can be improved.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for this clarification. It is actually just one binary variable that is indexed over 20 years hourly = 175200 hours. Here I opened a question about the linearisation of the quadratic constraints I had before, which started all these problems: I would very much appreciate if youd have a look at it: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69374790/linearization-of-quadratic-constraint)

Answer (score 1):

It works again :)
I am not 100% sure what was the issue but I think it was this:

```
if grid_limit != -1:
    def gridImportLimit_rule(m,y,ts):
        return m.gridImport[y,ts] <= grid_limit
    m.const_gridImportLimit = Constraint(year_i, ts_i, rule = gridImportLimit_rule)
    
    def gridExportLimit_rule(m,y,ts):
        return m.gridExport[y,ts] <= grid_limit
    m.const_gridExportLimit = Constraint(year_i, ts_i, rule = gridExportLimit_rule)
```

Whenever I used the -1 as an input to specify that I do not want to constrain the gird I ran into the problem mentioned. When I use a big limit instead (which has the same effect) the program works fine.

Cheers for your help :)